# Oracle: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: oracle

I have a query which works nice when I run it inside sqlplus:

```
SQL> SELECT  T_0.ID AS ATTR_1_, T_0_0.ID AS ATTR_2_,  
CASE  WHEN   ( T_0.ID=1 AND  ( T_0_0.ID=3 OR T_0_1.ID='val_1')  )  
THEN  'val_1' ELSE  'val_2' END  AS TXT, T_0_1.ID,  
CASE  WHEN  T_0.ID='boo' THEN  'boo' END  AS EXTRA_FIELD 
FROM TEST_TABLE T_0  
INNER JOIN TEST_TABLE_2 T_0_0  ON  ( T_0_0.ATTR=T_0.ID )  
INNER JOIN TEST_TABLE_3 T_0_1  ON  ( T_0_1.ID = T_0_0.ID )  
WHERE  (  ( T_0.ID=1 AND T_0_0.ID=3 )  
OR T_0_1.ID=2 OR T_0_0.TXT='val_2');

no rows selected
```

Although, it returns nothing, it still works and does not result in error. However, when I do the same thing in Python, using bindings, I get this error message:

```
 cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

This is how my query looks in Python, before I do cursor.execute:

```
SELECT  T_0.ID AS ATTR_1_, T_0_0.ID AS ATTR_2_,  
CASE  WHEN   ( T_0.ID=:TXT_ AND  ( T_0_0.ID=:TXT__ OR T_0_1.ID=:TXT___ )  )  
THEN  :TXT___ ELSE  :TXT____ END  AS TXT, T_0_1.ID,  
CASE  WHEN  T_0.ID=:EXTRA_FIELD THEN  :EXTRA_FIELD END  AS EXTRA_FIELD 
FROM TEST_TABLE T_0  
INNER JOIN TEST_TABLE_2 T_0_0  ON  ( T_0_0.ATTR=T_0.ID )  
INNER JOIN TEST_TABLE_3 T_0_1  ON  ( T_0_1.ID = T_0_0.ID )  
WHERE  (  ( T_0.ID=:ID AND T_0_0.ID=:ID_ )  
OR T_0_1.ID=:ID__ OR T_0_0.TXT=:TXT )
```

The query is just a string double-quoted "SELECT ..." . And this is how the dictionary with binding variables looks like:

```
OrderedDict([('TXT_', 1), ('TXT__', 3), ('TXT___', 'val_1'), 
('TXT____', 'val_2'), ('EXTRA_FIELD', 'boo'), ('ID', 1), 
('ID_', 3), ('ID__', 2), ('TXT', 'val_2')])
```

So, as you can see I have a perfect dictionary - number values are just numbers without quotes, string values are just strings with single quotes. I know, you will ask about the schema of the tables. So, here its is:

```
SQL> SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE
TABLE_NAME = 'TEST_TABLE';

COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------
DATA_TYPE
------------------------------
ID
NUMBER

SQL> SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE
TABLE_NAME = 'TEST_TABLE_2';

COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------
DATA_TYPE
------------------------------
ATTR
NUMBER

ID
NUMBER

TXT
VARCHAR2

SQL> SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEST_TABLE_3';

COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------
DATA_TYPE
------------------------------
ID
NUMBER
```

So, it seems like one and the same query works good in the console, but does not work when using Python. Why is that?

**EDIT**

And here is a proof - a screen of two console windows. In the first console I run the query in sqlplus, in the second console I print sql query and the dictionary, which is used for binding variables:

[image]

**EDIT**

Oh, it's even more interesting. I was able to reproduce this error in Oracle shell and it looks like Oracle 11c bug. So, look at this:

[image]

Please, pay attention to the fact that `ID` field has a `NUMBER` type. And then pay attention to these two screens:

[image]

In the screen above you can see that everything is ok. However, if we slightly change it by adding `OR T_0_1.ID=2` to the WHERE part, then it breaks:

[image]

So, this problem is reproducible even in Oracle shell. You can do it, using the schema I provided above.

**EDIT**

I updated the topic of my question, because it has nothing to do with Python. The whole problem with Oracle itself.

**EDIT**

BTW. My last comment does not contradict to the beginning part of my investigation. The thing is, if I have some data in TEST_TABLE_3, then the query breaks. And if I delete data, then is starts working. Here is a big proof:
[image]

How can data affect correctness of the query??

Comment: Did you try to narrow it down, to see where the thing breaks down? For example, comment out the two "INNER JOIN" lines and try to compile again; do you still get the error message? That will tell you where to look.

Comment: No, I have not tried that yet.

Comment: My query is generated by one of the auto-tests. Now I will try to hardcode it.

Comment: BTW, I can not comment out the last two JOINS, because I use fields from joined tables in SELECT ... part.

Comment: I managed to narrow it down. The whole problem is caused solely by WHERE part of the query. If I remove it and remove respective bindings, then its ok. But what is wrong with my bindings?

Comment: Re: not being able to comment out the joins, you could comment out the corresponding column names in the SELECT clause. Glad you were able to narrow it down to the WHERE clause... it may help to add that to your original post.

Comment: Are you able to replace the bind variables, one by one, with their literal values, to see when the error goes away? That will show you which bind variable gives you the problem.

Comment: Well, the problem is that my query is generated automatically by one of the tests. All the tests run ok, except this one. But what is interesting is that, if I code this manually in Python prompt, then I get no error, and like in sqlplus I get `[]`. May be it happens because of some mixture of quotes and string variables?

Comment: So, the error is not caused bt WHERE part. It was just first part that I commented out in code that I manually printed in Python console.

Comment: OK - then this is way out of my area of knowledge. Let's see what the python experts say.  Adding this info to your post should help them. Good luck!

Comment: @mathguy. If you have some time, please, have a look at the update. I managed to reproduce this problem in Oracle shell. It narrowed down just to one field from TEST_TABLE_3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your last screen just below the last line of the statement you have

```
CASE WHEN ( T_O.ID=1 AND ( T_0_0.ID=3 OR T_0_1.ID='VAL_1') )
```

there's an asterisk (now it helps, but sometimes it could lead in the wrong direction) showing the place of the encountered issue

```
T_0_1.ID='VAL_1'
```

in your table ID column is of Number type. 'VAL_1' - is Varchar.

As the comparison rules state:

> When comparing a character value with a numeric value, Oracle converts the character data to a numeric value.

see (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF00214)

when oracle encounters this it tries to cast your string to number - and you get the error

> How can data affect correctness of the query??

When there's no data in the table - there's no record returned from the table, hence there's no need the check the value of the column for equality - this comparison is not executed and  no error shown

Comment: Oh, I see. But it sounds like nonesense. Why does it try to cast and not simply compares a number to a string and decides that it is false? I tried this query in dozens other RDBMS and it works ok. In any programming language I know `1 == "val_1"` will return `false`. It seems like Oracle does too much and thinks where a programmer should think. Though, I see that it is as it is. Thanks!

Comment: well, this is just the way it is. Some languages are strict, some are not, others provide implicit data type conversion. Oracle in this case tries to 'help' you. But just a rule of thumb, not only for Oracle - never rely on implicit conversions. In your case - if you see there's a chance of comparing different data types - make an explicit cast like T_0_1.ID=TO_NUMBER('VAL_1')

Comment: I totally agree with your last advice. And in reality this is what I expected from Oracle. Its implicit casting (when you do not even want it) is not transparent and rather misleading.

Comment: @Jacobian - Glad you got your answer. I have to disagree with you on datatype checking though; most "professional grade" languages enforce strict data typing, meaning the code won't even compile, much less return anything at runtime.

Comment: @mathguy. You have a point there. Though I think there is nothing to disagree on, because there are dozens of "professional grade" dynamically typed languages as well. And as for the topic under discussion, my feeling of how it should work was based on what I see in other RDBMS, including MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite.