# The same query returns different results in the shell and in code

Tags: python, oracle

Previously, I stumbled across one interesting thing in Oracle - 
[Oracle: ORA-01722: invalid number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229344/oracle-ora-01722-invalid-number). It turned out to be Oracle's natural behaviour (though different from other major databases I dealt before - MySQL, Postgres and SQLite). But now I see another counterintuitive thing - I have a very simple query which returns results in the shell, but returns nothing from Python code. This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE T0 
INNER JOIN TEST_TABLE_2 T1 ON T1.ATTR=T0.ID 
INNER JOIN TEST_TABLE_3 T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
```

As you can see, it's a very simple query with just two simple joins. And here is voodoo magic screencast:

[image]

So, as you can see in the shell it returns data. Here is another picture of the ghost:

[image]

Now you see that in Python code it returns nothing. However, it does return if we tune this query a little bit - just remove the second join:

[image]

So, what is wrong with all that? And how can I trust Oracle? (now it just seems to me that I can rely more on a file database like SQLite, then on Oracle).

**EDIT**

Below is schema with data:

```
SQL> SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEST_TABLE';

COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------
DATA_TYPE
------------------------------
ID
NUMBER


SQL> SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE;

ID
----------
     1

SQL> SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEST_TABLE_2';

COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------
DATA_TYPE
------------------------------
ID
NUMBER

TXT
VARCHAR2

ATTR
NUMBER


SQL> SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE_2;

ID
----------
TXT
-----------------------------------
ATTR
----------
     2
hello
     1


SQL> SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEST_TABLE_3';

COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------
DATA_TYPE
------------------------------
ID
NUMBER


SQL> SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE_3;

ID
----------
     2
```

**EDIT**

To be more precise, I created my three tables with these statements:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(id number(19) default 0 not null)
CREATE TABLE test_table_2(txt varchar(255),id number(19) default 0 not null,attr number(19) default 0 not null)
CREATE TABLE test_table_3(id number(19) default 0 not null)
```

Comment: This does seem very odd, could you please add DDLs and example table content to your question? That way I can try to replicate this funny behaviour? Also - It's pretty hard to read the queries you've attached as screenshots, and with the changes in format you've made from query to query, it would be alot easier to analyze them if all queries were written as similar as possible.

Comment: Yes, sure. I will post additional information in a minute.

Comment: @Yaron Idan. I've made an update. Please, have a look.

Comment: Hm, it seems like I found what was wrong. It's really interesting:)

Comment: Yeah, I found the reason. It is really interesting, that cx_Oracle library allows to add garbage to the table. Or what it adds looks like normal data, but in reality it is not what you see. I will post what I mean in a minute.